# Button to change the color of the current item in a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a validate button inside each item of a recyclerView in order to change the color to green of the current item. When a new item is added in the recyclerview , I want to set the default background (no background color).

I've tried inside the BindView(position) function so by default when a new item is added in the itemsList, the color of the current element (item 0) is green whether I clicked on validate or not and that's not what I want.

I've also tried in the onBindViewHolder function but it doesnt work.

How can I change the color of this item in this recyclerview and this color remains the same whithout considering the index changing in the List if a new item is added?

I want that each new item of this recyclerview to be in the default color (background color white or no background color) and the item +n to be in the color of the corresponding status (validated = green , reschedulded = grey)

Once the validated button has been clicked I want the item to remains in read only mode.

Here is the code :

The adapter:

```
private Context context;
    private List<RideObject> itemList;

    public TestListeAdapter(List<RideObject> itemList, Context context) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public TestListeAdapter.TestListeViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_testliste, null, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new TestListeAdapter.TestListeViewHolders(layoutView);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull TestListeAdapter.TestListeViewHolders holder, final int position) {
       

        holder.bindView(position);

       if (holder.validated){

            holder.mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.teal_700));
        }
```

the viewholder Class :

```
class TestListeViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //MyClickListener  listener;
        TextView rideId;
   
        ImageView mCheck;
        ImageView mreschedulded;
    
        CardView mCard;
      

        TestListeViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           
            mCheck = itemView.findViewById(R.id.validate);
            mreschedulded= itemView.findViewById(R.id.reschedulded);
          
            mCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
         
     

        }

        private void bindView(int pos) {
            RideObject item = itemList.get(pos);

      


            mCheck.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                item.setRDVHour(timePicker.getHour());
                item.setRDVMinute(timePicker.getMinute());
                validated = true;
                item.setValider(true);
                item.confirmDriver();

                //if (itemList.size() == 1){

                    //mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(), R.color.teal_700));
                //itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(),R.color.teal_700));

                });



            mreschedulded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    timePicker.setEnabled(true);
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(),R.color.grey));

                }
            });


        }

    }
```

In the MainActivity:

```
     resultsTestList.add(0,  mCurrentRide);
     mTestListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Ive tried the code in the answer but it doesnt work . Currently, the setbackgroundcolor applies just to  the  first element of the list. I would want that if the first element (item0) goes to second element (item1) the item keep his color background which is not the case with the given answer code

Comment: Where is `validated` declared?

Comment: Here :      mCheck.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                item.setRDVHour(timePicker.getHour());
                item.setRDVMinute(timePicker.getMinute());
                **bold**  `validated = true;`
                item.setValider(true);
                item.confirmDriver();


                });

Comment: That's where you set it but I can't see `boolean validated` anywhere

Comment: initially here :  class TestListeViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //MyClickListener  listener;
        ImageView mCheck;
        ImageView mreschedulded;
        CardView mCard;
  
        Boolean validated = false;
        Spinner spinnerTests;
        TimePicker timePicker;
        private int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 15;
        NumberPicker minutePicker;
        List<String> displayedValues;
        FloatingActionButton mCall;

Comment: I didn't copy all the code but thats not the problem . Take into account that this variable is declarated but do you have an answer to the question?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. `ViewHolder` should never have `validated` as it's variable.(as I wrote in my answer?)

Answer (score 0):

When binding RecyclerView items, you have to think of it as that you need to change the ViewHolder completely disregarding the previous state.

The view holder should not hold key information like `validated`.
Whether the view holder stays in the validated state or not should depend on the item it is being bind to.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NotNull TestListeAdapter.TestListeViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.bindView(position);
}
```

...

```
    private void bindView(int pos) {
        RideObject item = itemList.get(pos);
        
        if (item.validated) {
            mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(...R.color.teal_700));
        else {
            mCard.setCardBackgroundColor(...R.color.grey));
            mCheck.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                item.setRDVHour(timePicker.getHour());
                item.setRDVMinute(timePicker.getMinute());
                item.validated = true;
                item.setValider(true);
                item.confirmDriver();
            });

            mReschedulded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    timePicker.setEnabled(true);
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context.getApplicationContext(),R.color.grey));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your code set the background color for a new added item at the position 0. So the n-1 item is still with a background color white. Its seems like the holder object always represents the item at the position 0. I want that the item background remains the same if the item is in position 1 or 2,....n for example

Comment: @Coco Updated the answer to explain it further.